# Vuetify Mobile Fill Entire Screen in Portrait

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When I test my app in mobile portrait mode it looks like this:

[Mobile portrait](https://nimb.ws/7HlnjB)

But I'm trying to make it look like this from [Vuetify](https://nimb.ws/QbXr9l)

In landscape its fantastic, portrait no luck. I'm using `fluid` and `fill-height` on the `v-container` but no luck.

I've also tried `height="100vh"` on the container but that also didn't work.

This is some sample code that's been simplified and it doesn't work either:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid fill-height>
    <v-layout>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center" class="mx-auto">
        <v-col cols="8">
          <v-card 
            outlined
            class="d-flex"
          >
            <v-text-field
              color="#F03C99"
              label="Email"
              placeholder="Email for Your Showroom"
              outlined 
              class="ml-4"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

I'm starting to think that it might be that I'm using `router-view` this is what I have in my router

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view name="navigation" :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    <router-view class="fill-height" key="main"></router-view>
    <router-view name="confirm"></router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Here is my real code:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid fill-height>
    <v-layout>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center" class="mx-auto">
        <v-col :cols="overallColumns">
          <v-card 
            outlined
          >
            <v-row>
              <v-col
                :cols="accountForImage"
                align="start"
              >
                <v-card-title>
                  <v-img src='small-bella-logo.png' max-height="41px" max-width="128px" contain></v-img>
                </v-card-title>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="email"
                    color="#F03C99"
                    label="Email"
                    :rules="[rules.email]"
                    placeholder="Email for Your Showroom"
                    outlined 
                    class="ml-4"
                    :class="marginRight"
                    :error-messages="errorMessage"
                    data-cy="login"
                  ></v-text-field>

                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="password"
                    color="#F03C99"
                    label="Password"
                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                    outlined 
                    class="ml-4"
                    :class="marginRight"
                    :append-icon="passwordVisible ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'"
                    :type="passwordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'"
                    @click:append="passwordVisible = !passwordVisible"
                    data-cy="password"
                  ></v-text-field>


                  <v-row 
                    class="mt-n5"
                  >
                    <v-col 
                      :cols="stackColumns"
                      align="start">
                      <v-btn 
                        color="#AF3482" 
                        class="white--text ml-4"
                        data-cy="login-button" 
                        @click="logInWithBella"
                      >LOGIN</v-btn>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col 
                      :cols="stackColumns"
                      :align="alignStackedColumnToEnd"
                      class="mt-2"
                      :class="marginLeftWhenStacked"
                      >
                      <h1
                        @click="forgotPassword"
                        class="caption font-weight-bold ml-4 pointer pink_text"
                      >FORGOT PASSWORD?</h1>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>

                  <v-row align="center" justify="center">
                    <v-col cols="12" align="center" justify="center">
                      <v-divider class="ml-4"></v-divider>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>

                  <v-row 
                    justify="space-between"
                  >
                    <v-col
                      :cols="columnsFiveAndTwelve"
                      :align="alignStackedColumnToCenter"
                      justify="start">
                      <v-btn
                        class="ml-4 white--text"
                        color="#3B5998"
                        @click="logInWithFacebook()"
                        medium>
                        LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col
                      :cols="columnsFiveAndTwelve"
                      :align="alignStackedColumnToCenter"
                      justify="end">
                      <v-btn
                        class="white--text"
                        :class="marginLeftAndNegativeLeft"
                        color="#DB4437"
                        @click="logInWithGoogle()"
                        medium
                        >
                        LOGIN WITH GOOGLE
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>

                  <v-row align="center" justify="center">
                    <v-col cols="12" align="center" justify="center">
                      <v-divider class="ml-4"></v-divider>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>

                  <v-row align="start" justify="center">
                    <v-col cols="12" align="start" justify="center">
                      <h1 class=" ml-4 font title font-weight-regular">
                        No Account?
                      </h1>
                      <v-btn
                        class="ml-4 white--text mt-2"
                        :class="marginBottom"
                        color="#AF3482"
                        block
                        @click="sendAndCreateToken"
                        >
                        SIGN UP AND CREATE SHOWROOM
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-form>
              </v-col>

              <v-col 
                cols="6" 
                align="center" 
                class=""
                v-if="removeImage"
              >
                <v-img src="login.png" class="mt-10" max-height="519px" max-width="187px" contain></v-img>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <p>{{ $vuetify.breakpoint.name }}</p>   
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: In your basic example, setting `class="fill-height"` on `v-card` gets it to fill the container ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vuetify-vite-starter-phpfl1?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FBasicExample.vue)). Can you update the demo to create a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @tony19 arghh, still no luck.. I'm starting to think it might be because everything is in a `router-view` let me update the OP and also provide a link to the project

Comment: @tony19 the interesting thing is that when I display the breakpoint name in your example it shows as `xs` but in mine it shows as `md` and both cases its `mobile` true.. I'm pretty sure that's the issue

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fork of the demo I linked?